# How can I make a multi-level(3 level) navigation drawer in android?

Tags: navigation, drawer

I am developing an android application where I need to put a navigation drawer which would have more than 3 levels.

What I want to do: If I click one item of my list in the drawer, a whole new list comes up in the drawer. This new list should also do the same when items of this list are clicked. This could go on for many levels.

I am a newbie in android development, try to add details to your ideas. Thanks!
source code eclipse
[image]